# What is this._id in meteor's leader-board example?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

In meteor's leader-board example there is a bit of code that uses this._id to set "selected_player", which used to update the players database. Here is the client-side code:

```
  Template.leaderboard.players = function () {
    return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});
  };

  Template.leaderboard.selected_name = function () {
    var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
    return player && player.name;
  };

  Template.player.selected = function () {
    return Session.equals("selected_player", this._id) ? "selected" : '';
  };

  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click input.inc': function () {
      Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: 5}});
    }
  });

  Template.player.events({
    'click': function () {
      Session.set("selected_player", this._id);
      console.log(this._id);
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see, this._id is never set (e.g `this._id = some_id;`), so how does the program get it? How does it know which player is selected?

You can see a video about the example and get the rest of the code here: [Leader Board Example](https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor uses the [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) templating system (with some extensions). `Template.player.selected` is a template helper...in which `this` is equal to the current "context". This means `this._id` is equal to the `_id` of the player being rendered/displayed.

See the [template helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers) section of the handlebars docs for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%401.2.1/packages/spacebars/README.md#helper-arguments), the template engine used by Meteor, says:

> The helper's implementation can access the current data context as `this`.

You then have to understand how data contexts work. This is covered at: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts

Basically, whenever you use a block tag like `#each`, it creates a new data context, in which helper methods and the block are evaluated.

In the case of `#each`, the data context cycles over each object of the collection.

We can also further observe things with:

```
Template.player.events({
  'click': function () {
    Session.set('selectedPlayer', this._id);
    console.log(this._id)
    console.log(this.constructor.toString())
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this))
    console.log(typeof(this._id))
  }
});
```

which outputs on the browser console when we click on a scientist:

```
function Object() {
    [native code]
}
Array [ "name", "score", "_id" ]
CdpeDAcEnkdFF3Yu2
string
```

In this example, the data context corresponds to outputs of `Mongo.Collection.find()`, which are MongoDB documents. `_id` is automatically added by Mongo.

Inside the block tag, the properties of the current data context can now be used directly as in:

```
<span class="name">{{name}}</span>
<span class="score">{{score}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here **this._id** is object id of currently representing item in mongodb.Here you want to update record.To update that record you should have one reference value so here this._id is your reference value to update record.